# Complex table Join at sql

Tags: sql, join

[image: [My Tables Diagram ]]

Pls i want to get data from Articles Table according to PressKit Table Data

i need help how to join between Articles Table and PressKit Table

while i have to different intermediate Tabled between them?

i want to get data like that

```
 SELECT ArticleID ,
        ArticaleTile
 FROM   Articles
 WHERE  dbo.MagazineID IN (
        SELECT  dbo.Magazines.MagazineID
        FROM    dbo.Magazines
                INNER JOIN dbo.PressKitMagazines ON dbo.Magazines.MagazineID = dbo.PressKitMagazines.MagazineID
        WHERE   PressKitID = @PressKitID )
        AND ClassID IN (
        SELECT  Class.classID
        FROM    dbo.Class
                INNER JOIN dbo.PressKitClass ON Class.classID = PressKitClass.classID
        WHERE   PressKitID = @PressKitID )
```

Comment: Select ArticleID,ArticaleTile from Articles ......... ..... where PressKitID=@PressKitID                                                                                i need help at join statment

Comment: "get data from ... Table according to .. Table Data" & "join between ... Table and ... Table" are not clear. Use more words and simple sentences that explain what you mean instead of vague words like "get" & "according to" & "between". What does a row say when in each table? What does a row say when in the result of your query? Show your table definitions and example input & output.

Comment: i take to so long .. i want to remove "where IN " with Join

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle
FROM Articles a
JOIN dbo.PressKitMagazines pm
ON a.MagazineID = pm.MagazineID AND pm.PressKitID = @PressKitID
JOIN dbo.PressKitClass pc
ON a.ClassID = pc.ClassID AND pc.PressKitID = @PressKitID
```

You do not need to involve `Magazines`, `Class` or `PressKit` because you do not need to return the `Name`s associated with their `ID`s. You didn't need them in your original query either:

```
SELECT ArticleID, ArticleTitle
FROM Articles
WHERE MagazineID IN (
    SELECT MagazineID
    FROM dbo.PressKitMagazines
    WHERE PressKitID = @PressKitID )
AND ClassID IN (
    SELECT classID
    FROM dbo.PressKitClass
    WHERE PressKitID = @PressKitID )
```

Suppose that table `T` holds the rows that make some statement parameterized by its columns into a true statement. Eg `Articles` holds the rows that satisfy:
    "article *ArticleID* titled *ArticleTitle* was in magazine *MagazineID* & was of class *ClassID*"
or in shorthand:
    Article(ArticleID, ArticleTitle, MagazineID, ClassID)
Inside an SQL SELECT statement, a table's column names are prefixed by an alias and a dot (which can be left out when there's no ambiguity):
    a(a.ArticleID, a.ArticleTitle, a.MagazineID, a.ClassID)
So the rows in:
    `SELECT C FROM U WHERE C IN (SELECT C FROM T WHERE`*`condition`*`)`
or with prefixes and dots:
    `SELECT U.C FROM U WHERE U.C IN (SELECT T.C FROM T WHERE`*`condition`*`)`
are the rows where:
    `SELECT U.C FROM U JOIN T ON`*`condition`*`AND U.C = T.C`
because they both return rows with just column C where:
    U(...,U.C,...) AND T(...,T.C,...) AND *condition* AND U.C = T.C

For composing queries see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097).

Comment: Thanx philipxy it works

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It just does an INNER JOIN to the tables with the PressKitID you're looking for and then a simple WHERE clause can determine the specific parameter you want:

```
SELECT 
    a.ArticleID, a.ArticleTitle
FROM articles AS a
INNER JOIN PressKitMagazines AS m
ON a.magazineid = m.magazineid
INNER JOIN PressKitClass AS c
ON a.classid = c.classid
WHERE
    m.PressKitID = @PressKitID
    OR
    c.PressKitID = @PressKitID
```

Comment: The original query returns articles with a magazine *and* class from those of the given press kit. This returns articles with either a magazine or a class from those of the given press kit.

Comment: Agreed.  I took the original question (not query) as wanting the article table information if there exists a matching @PressKitID so I used OR so it will return a result regardless of whether there is both a magazine and class, or just one.  If it does require both a magazine and class then change the OR to AND in the WHERE clause.  I'll update my query if the original post is edited with additional specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the problem is however I suggest using EXISTS, like this:

```
SELECT
      A.ArticleID
    , A.ArticaleTile
FROM Articles AS A
WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM dbo.Magazines AS M
                  INNER JOIN dbo.PressKitMagazines AS PKM ON M.MagazineID = PKM.MagazineID
            WHERE M.PressKitID = @PressKitID
                  AND A.ArticleID = M.MagazineID
      )
    OR EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM dbo.Class AS C
                  INNER JOIN dbo.PressKitClass PKK ON C.classID = PKK.classID
            WHERE C.PressKitID = @PressKitID
                  AND A.ClassID = C.ClassID
      )
```

I also believe you need to use **OR** between those two subqueries in the where clause.